# MySQL JOIN 2 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables as below:

Suits

```
| id | hotel_id |   name   |  etc ...
  1        3      Some name
  2        3      SomeName2
```

Orders

```
| id | suits | etc ...
   1    1,2
```

I want to get order list from database with suit names as below:

```
| id | hotel_id |        suits       | etc ...
   1      3      Some name, SomeName2
```

I'm trying with this code:

```
            SELECT
            o.id,
            h.name as hotel,
            o.hotel as hotel_id,
            s.name
            FROM h_orders o
            LEFT JOIN hotels h ON o.hotel = h.id
            LEFT JOIN suits s ON o.suits = s.id
            WHERE o.user_id = ? GROUP BY o.id ORDER BY o.id DESC
```

But getting only first suit name. How can I get result as mentioned above? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normalize the schema. Read ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|191.1113)

Comment: if you have 'have tables as below' then this 'LEFT JOIN hotels h ON o.hotel = h.id' is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should fix your data model.  Storing numeric ids in a column is bad for many reasons:

- Numbers should not be stored as strings.
- Strings should not be used to store multiple values.
- Ids should have properly declared foreign key relationships.
- SQL has poor string handling functionality.
- SQL has a great way to store lists.  It is called a *table*, not a *column*.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad decisions.  If that is the case, you can do what you want using `find_in_set()`.

Because you are using `left join`s, I assume that you want all rows even when there is no match.  That suggests:

```
SELECT o.id, o.hotel as hotel_id, GROUP_COCNAT(s.name SEPARTOR ', ') as suits
FROM h_orders o LEFT JOIN
     hotels h
     ON o.hotel = h.id LEFT JOIN
     suits s
     ON FIND_IN_SET(s.id, o.suits) > 0
WHERE o.user_id = ?
GROUP BY o.id, o.hotel
ORDER BY o.id DESC;
```

However, you should put your focus into fixing the data model.

Also, it is not clear why you would have a `LEFT JOIN` from `orders` to `hotels`.  Is it possible to have an "order" without a valid "hotel"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT 
  o.id,
  h.name as hotel,
  h.id as hotel_id,
  group_concat(s.name) as suits
FROM h_orders o 
LEFT JOIN suits s ON o.suits = s.id
LEFT JOIN hotels h ON o.hotel = h.id
WHERE o.user_id = ? AND FIND_IN_SET(s.id, o.suits)
GROUP BY o.id, h.name, h.id 
ORDER BY o.id DESC
```

I kept the condition `o.user_id = ?` in the query although you did not explain what it is needed for.

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, doesn't worked. 
Same as first query, returns all data with only first suit name.

Comment: Do you need the join of the table `hotels`? You did not post sample data for it. It would be better if you created a fiddle here:https://www.db-fiddle.com with data so I can test,